# Wrong letter in a list - Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to do the following: i have the events

```
word([p,r,o,l,o,g]).
word([p,r,o,l,o,g]).
```

i need to find the letter that is wrong :

```
e.x wrong_letter([p,r,o,l,o,u,g],X).<br>
X=u
```

thay's my program but is not working :

```
wrong_letter([X|Y],L) :- 
word(H),
member(X,H),
wrong_letter(Y,L).
```

thanks in advance, Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one wrong letter (an added letter) in your input word you could:

- Take a word
- Split into two sublists (Head and Tail), using `append/3`
- Test to see if your input word unifies with the Head, an added letter, and the Tail; again using `append/3`

That would look:

```
wrong_letter(WrongWord, Letter):-
  word(Word),
  append(Head, Tail, Word),
  append(Head, [Letter|Tail], WrongWord).
```

Test:

```
?- wrong_letter([p,r,o,l,o,u,g], X).
X = u ;
```

You could also achieve the same effect using `select/3`:

```
wrong_letter(WrongWord, Letter):-
  word(Word),
  select(Letter, WrongWord, Word).
```